# Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2 の対策

Tags: swift, realm

Realm入門という本の「06_モデルオブジェクトの生成と初期化」の下記サンプルコードをダウンロードして使おうとXcode9.1で開いた所、エラーが出て前に進めません。解決方法を御教示頂けないでしょうか。

#### エラー内容

ModelCreationのViewController.swift/import RealmSwiftのところに

```
Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2
```

#### 試したこと

ネットで探して以下の４点を試しました。
①`carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`
（結果→`-bash: carthage: command not found`）
②`$ brew update`／`$ brew install carthage`をやった（結果→ `command not found`。）
③`Carthage.pkg` をダウンロードしてインストール後に①（結果→ `command not found`。）
④`build holder`のクリーン後に①（結果→ `command not found`。）

環境　MacBookPro HighSierra10.13.1 Xcode9.1

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    dynamic var dog: Dog?   // Dogモデルと1対1の関連
    let cats = List<Cat>()  // Catモデルと1対多の関連
}

class Animal: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}

class Dog: Animal {
}

class Cat: Animal {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // MARK: - 6.2 生成と初期化する方法
        print("6.2 生成と初期化する方法(p035)")
        
        print("- ①生成後に各プロパティ値を設定する(p036)")
        var dog = Dog()
        dog.name = "Momo"
        dog.age = 9
        
        print("- ②キー値コーディング(KVC)に準拠しているオブジェクトで初期化する(p036)")
        dog = Dog(value: ["name": "Momo", "age": 9]) // Dictionaryで初期化
        
        print("- ③各プロパティの値の配列で初期化する(p036)")
        dog = Dog(value: ["Momo", 9])
        
        // MARK: - 6.3 ネストしたモデルオブジェクトの生成と初期化
        print("6.3 ネストしたモデルオブジェクトの生成と初期化(p037)")
        
        let cat1 = Cat(value: ["Toto", 1])
        let cat2 = Cat(value: ["Rao", 2])
        
        print("- ①生成後に各プロパティ値を設定する(p037)")
        var person = Person()
        person.name = "Yu"
        person.age = 32
        person.dog = dog
        person.cats.append(objectsIn: [cat1, cat2])
        
        print("- ②キー値コーディング(KVC)に準拠しているオブジェクトで初期化する(p037)")
        person = Person(value: ["name": "Yu",
                                "age": 32,
                                "dog": ["name": "Momo", "age": 9],
                                "cats": [["name": "Toto", "age": 1],
                                         ["name": "Rao", "age": 2]]])
        
        // Objectもキー値コーディングに準拠しているので初期化に使用できます。
        person = Person(value: ["name": "Yu",
                                "age": 32,
                                "dog": dog,
                                "cats": [cat1, cat2]])
        
        print("- ③各プロパティの値の配列で初期化する(p038)")
        person = Person(value: ["Yu",
                                32,
                                dog,
                                [cat1, cat2]])
        
        // オプショナル型やListクラス内の要素がない場合でも、配列内の値を省略することはできません。
        // 値がない場合はnilを指定する必要があります。
        person = Person(value: ["Yu",
                                32,
                                nil,
                                nil] as [Any?])
        
        // 例えば次のコードはオプショナル型とList型に対しての要素がないためクラッシュする。
        // person = Person(value: ["Yu", 32]) // ← 実行すると例外が発生しクラッシュ
    }
    
    // MARK: - Util
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    
    func print(_ string: String) {
        Swift.print(string)
        if textView.text.characters.count > 0 {
            textView.text = textView.text.appending("\n")
        }
        textView.text = textView.text.appending(string)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
サンプルソースにある、このプロジェクトのディレクトリをダウンロードしたディレクトリとは異なる場所に移動してから、プロジェクトを開き、中のRealmと、RealmSwiftのframeworkを削除して、使用しているXcodeのバージョンに対応したRealmと、RealmSwiftのframeworkをインストールしたところ、simulatorで動きました。
インストールは、この本の「第３章Realmのインストール（DynamicFrameworkによるインストール）」に従いました。
コンパイルをする段階にバージョンの違いがあると思い込んでいましたが、frameworkそのものにXcodeのバージョンに対応しているものがあることを理解しました。carthageの問題ではありませんでした。